# Get unique values from Json Object

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to get all algorithms from the public what to mine api:

```js
var lookup = {}
var result = []

axios.get('https://whattomine.com/calculators.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    for (var item, i = 0; item = response["coins"][i++];) {
      var algorithm = item.algorithm

      if (!(algorithm in lookup)) {
        lookup[algorithm] = 1
        result.push(algorithm)
      }
    }
    console.log(result)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see I am using axios to query the api. Then I would like to filter all algorithms that are not in lookup.

As a result I would like to  have:
`[]`

However, I currently get `['Keccak', 'Scrypt-OG', 'X11']` back.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I guess, you are trying to output your `result` variable before your axios call resolves.

Comment: @DavidR I  just put my results variable in the axios promise, and  I still get nothing back...

Comment: the `response` does't have `coins`, use `response.data.coins`

Comment: @joaner You're spot on!.. making the `response` to `response.data.coins` is indeed returns an empty array.. Checkout here => https://jsfiddle.net/5Ljshzkt/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, `response` is an Object with a `data` property, containing the actual response. Also, you're trying to loop over them as if it were an Array, but it is an Object with coin names as properties. [Lodash](https://lodash.com) can make your life easier:

```js
axios.get('https://whattomine.com/calculators.json')
  .then(response => {
    const coins = response.data.coins;
    const result = _.uniq(_.map(coins, item => item.algorithm));
    console.log(result);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

- [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) allows you to loop over an Array or an Object, which is useful here.
- [`_.uniq()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniq) will remove any duplicate from an Array of values.

Answer (score 2):

You should see the data structure: key of `coins` is string, not number like i++

```js
var lookup = {}
var result = []

axios.get('https://whattomine.com/calculators.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    for (var key in response.data["coins"]) {
      var item = response.data["coins"][key]
      var algorithm = item.algorithm

      if (!(algorithm in lookup)) {
        lookup[algorithm] = 1
        result.push(algorithm)
      }
    }
    console.log(result)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```